# Call prototype function from onclick event, when button is added dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have two prototype functions `showPopup` and `buildView`. In `buildView`, I am generating a dynamic HTML with a button and would like to call `showPoup` when button is clicked. However, when button is clicked, it throws

> Error: The value of the property 'showPopup' is null or undefined, not
>   a Function object

```
MyEditor.prototype.buildView = function(id) {
   document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='showPopup(getName(id), getPlace(id))' />";
}

MyEditor.prototype.showPopup = function(name, place) { }
```

I even tried using `onclick='MyEditor.showPopup(getName(id), getPlace(id))'`, didn't work either.

Comment: Does the instantiation ever have any relevance?

Comment: Is there anything in the `#myView` element before `buildView` runs? Does `buildView()` have to empty out that element first?

Comment: @Phil `#myView` is an empty div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have to call `this.showPopup()`, which is only possible if you build up the DOM manually:

```
 MyEditor.prototype.buildView = function(id) {
    const button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "Edit";
    button.onclick = (evt) => {
      this.showPopup(getName(id), getPlace(id));
    };

     document.getElementById("myView").appendChild(button);
  }
```

Comment: Won't you lose the `this` context within the `onclick` function?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create your element via `document.createElement()`
2. Attach a *click* event listener to the element using an arrow function to preserve the `this` context
3. Empty out the `#myView` element of all child nodes
4. Append the element to your `#myView` element

```js
MyEditor.prototype.buildView = function(id) {
  const btn = document.createElement('input')
  btn.type = 'button';
  btn.value = 'Edit'
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.showPopup(getName(id), getPlace(id))
  }, false)

  // empty out #myView
  const view = document.getElementById('myView')
  while (view.firstChild) {
    view.removeChild(view.firstChild)
  }
  view.appendChild(btn)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build element by html text, you need do something like this.

```js
MyEditor = function() {};
MyEditor.prototype.buildView = function(id) {
    document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='editor.showPopup(\"name\", \"id\")' />";
}

MyEditor.prototype.showPopup = function(name, place) { 
    console.log(name)
}

var editor = new MyEditor()
editor.buildView();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
    <body>
        <div id="myView"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```